# Are there existing forums/QA sites specific to PS3 or Xbox360 development?

Tags: xbox360, playstation3

I'm wondering if there are existing forums, or sites similar to this one, that are targeted specifically to PS3 developers, or possibly, targeted specifically towards Xbox 360 developers?  Is all of this information proprietary, and therefore "secret," or do communities of developers for these platforms exist?

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All 3 platform holders provide forums / newsgroups which are strictly for registered (licensed) developers only. In general they provide a second tier of support for developers, allowing folks to share problems and solutions in a shared forum with the developer support teams also read. It is a specific part of the licence agreement that the development SDKs and any information about them is not shared outwith the developer or those secure shared forums/newsgroups.

XNA on X360 development and PS3 Linux are allowed by Microsoft and Sony. Anything else (Wii, PSP, etc.) is home-brew only and not sanctioned (since it involves hacking the hardware); although that's not to say there aren't plenty of forums out there for that.

Comment: Development on PS3 Linux does not require permission from Sony, although they have deprecated/removed it from current PS3s, and you don't have access to the blu-ray or video card.

Comment: Oh yes, you're absolutely right, I forgot about that. Will amend the answer accordingly

Comment: Yeah, I started to realize that based on the various NDAs, I would be unlikely to find anything outside of their sanctioned sites.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

PS3 DevNet has forums I think, but I've never used them. MS provides developer support via email, but no list/forum that I've seen. In both cases you need to have a contract with them and be under NDA yada yada. If you are doing XNA/CC for the Xbox there are plenty of forums for that at least. There are some forums out there that have more than their fair share of professional devs, but thats all unofficial.